# Getting an error while passing an expression as a fucntion parameter

Tags: scala

```
scala> def sum(a:Int)={a} //I have defined the function with a single parameter
sum: (a: Int)Int

sum{val b=10+20} //passing the parameter as expression block

Getting error

scala> sum{val b=10+20}
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
              sum{val b=10+20}
```

Why is it expecting `Unit` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is that `{val b = 10 + 20}` is of type `Unit` while `sum` is expecting an `Int`.

You can either call sum directly without assigning the variable:

```
sum(10 + 20)
> 30
```

Or make the block return an `Int`, like:

```
sum{
    val b = 10 + 20
    b // return b, which is an Int
}
> 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass an expression but a block with one declaration. Try:

```
sum(10+20)
```

You are experiencing a weird combination of syntax error and type-system convention.

The curly braces mark a block (see e.g. the body of your sum function declaration). Function arguments can be passed in juxtaposition or using parenthesis. That is your syntax error.

The type system convention allows languages with side-effects to gently insert these effects into basically any expression. This happens by treating the composition of statements (i.e. the semicolon) as "evaluate these expression but do nothing with the result, then evaluate the next expression". The *nothing as result* part is combined with the unit type for statements that do not compute anything.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the OP's code.The `val` is the problem, not the {}

Comment: I assume that the OP does not want to pass a block, but rather a simple argument. Thus it üprobably *is* a syntax error on his/her part. The fact that it is actually a syntactically valid expression seems to be pure coincidence.

Comment: Exactly. There is no syntax error. Without the val, it works `sum{10+20}`

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(a:Int)={a}
```

What this statement does is create a method that takes one `Int`-typed parameter and returns it.

```
sum{val b=10+20}
```

Here you pass a value to your defined method `sum`. What you're passing is an expression. Scala will, effectively, 'rewrite' that expression before applying it to `sum`. If we write the expression being passed (`val b=10+20`) in the REPL we will see what it gets rewritten to:

```
scala> val b=10+20
b: Int = 30
```

But this is only part of the story, because the assignment of a value to a name returns nothing. We can see this by putting brackets around the assignment:

```
scala> { val b=10+20 }
```

Note that the REPL displays nothing when this happens.

Because the re-written expression includes this evaluation, you're actually passing a scope to the function, in which `b` is defined. However, that scope doesn't 'return' an `Int` to be bound to `a`. To return the result of the `b` assignment, you have to do one of two things. Either you have to have a call to the variable be the last call in the expression, or have the last call be the calculation itself, and don't assign that to a variable:

```
sum{ val b=10+20; b } // Explicitly call the bound variable
sum{ 10 + 20 }  // Don't assign the variable
```